# How to use mobx-react 'observer' without decorator syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to shoe horn `mobx` into a vr application I am making with react 360. I've tried to use the decorator syntax but after wasting a solid chunk of time trying to implement it, I've decided to use the nondecorator syntax. Here is an example that I came across from the mobx documentation that I have a question on. Here is the code:

```javascript
import {observer} from "mobx-react";

var timerData = observable({
    secondsPassed: 0
});

setInterval(() => {
    timerData.secondsPassed++;
}, 1000);

@observer class Timer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<span>Seconds passed: { this.props.timerData.secondsPassed } </span> )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Timer timerData={timerData} />, document.body);
```

Notice the `observer` declaration on the `Timer` class. The documentation states this.

> Note that using @observer as decorator is optional, observer(class Timer ... { }) achieves exactly the same.

Would this be the correct way of implementing `Timer`?

```javascript
observer(class Timer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<span>Seconds passed: { this.props.timerData.secondsPassed } </span> )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 11):

Concerning the code snippet you have added I don't know whether it is a valid way or not, but here's the way I'm using MobX without the decorator syntax in my application project:

Create your MobX store, say `MyStore.js` like the following:

```
import {observable, action, computed, decorate} from 'mobx';

export default class MyStore {
    storeMap = observable(new Map());
    storeArray = observable([]);
    storeBoolean = false

    get storeMapSize() {
        return this.storeMap.size;
    }

    setStoreBoolean(value) {
        this.storeBoolean = value;
    }
}

decorate(MyStore, {
    storeMap: observable,
    storeArray: observable,
    storeBoolean: observable

    storeMapSize: computed,

    setStoreBoolean: action
});
```

Then in your component `Timer.js`:

```
import {inject, observer} from "mobx-react";

class Timer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<span>value from store: { this.props.myStore.storeMap.get('any_key') } </span> )
    }
}

export default inject('myStore')(observer(Timer));
```

and you can create as many stores as you want and inject all of them to your components using the same `inject` method and use them in the same way via `this.props`, for example

`export default inject('myStore', 'anotherStore', 'anotherNewStore')(observer(Timer));`

Comment: See mobx docs for most up to date usage: https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html. @Mis94 looks like you are doing double work in your MyStore example.